# Type of a global object dependent on boolean flag (determined at runtime)

Tags: c++, c++14, auto-ptr

I want to do something like the following

```
if (flag) {
  type1_t object = .....
} else {
  type2_t object = .....
}

// do the same thing with object
```

`type1_t` and `type2_t` are custom classes. The problem with the above snippet is `object` remains local to each if else clause, but I can't define it above the if-else because the type is dependent on `flag`.

Late edit: It seems I can't use C++17 features in this codebase I'm working with so the `std::variant` idea won't work.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` has been deprecated since C++11, so it's definitely _not_ the solution here.

Comment: @Martel yes sorry I misunderstood what auto_ptr did

Comment: An important consideration here is `flag` -- is its value known during pre-processing? (If not, when is its value determined?)

Comment: Your title says "static object" but your use of an `if` statement suggests that the initialization occurs inside a function. Could you clarify this? Either remove "static" from the title or mention in the body that the object is being declared at global scope and the `if` statement is just illustrating intended behavior.

Comment: @JaMiT `flag` is a boolean only known at runtime, I think. I suppose we could make it a template variable, but we haven't done that yet. Yeah, sorry for the "static" terminology. I had a hard time figuring out how to describe it in the title. I'll edit it to mention that it's declared at global scope

Comment: @roulette01 Since `flag` is not known until runtime, how do you delay initializing the global object until after `flag` is known? Globals (and many statics) are initialized before `main()` executes.

Comment: Are `type1_t` and `type2_t` related? If not, are you allowed/willing to make them related using polymorphism?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `std::variant` here. Something like

```cpp
std::variant<std::monostate, type1_t, type2_t> object;
if (flag) { ... } else { ... }
```

Notice the usage of `std::monostate`. That's because `std::variant`'s default constructor uses the first alternative's default constructor. `std::monostate` is here to avoid that.

Besides, `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated long time ago. `std::unique_ptr` is much better

Comment: oh sorry, I misunderstood what `auto_ptr` was. I thought it did something else

Comment: I will look into using `std;:variant`. Does it have any advantages over my ternary operator idea?

Comment: @roulette01 `std::variant` has the advantage that it works :-)